# How to find a week between two dates (SQL)

Tags: sql

How can I select a week, implying it's like a table which has :

- a starting date
- an ending date

Between two other dates (for example, of an event)?

For instance (using US dates), I have

- 06/01/2015 -> 06/07/2015 for the targeted week

And

- 05/25/2015 -> 07/01/2015 for the entire period of the event

I want the query to only return Weeks in-between the period of the event.
I am able to provide the starting and ending dates of the week (data from a selected WPF calendar), but I just can't figure out how to do that in a single SQL query.

I'm using SQL Management Studio 2010

Comment: I think you got the wrong tag for your post. Please tag it as SQL. And also specify which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Yes, it's just entire weeks (Monday to Sunday), as seen on a calendar. All of the weeks have a monday as starting date, and a sunday as ending date.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Why is 06/08/2014 -> 06/15/2014 not also in your target?

Comment: `Sun.06/01/2014` and `Sat.06/07/2014` and then `Sun.05/25/2014` and `Tue.07/01/2014` so, what is the deal ? Would be easier if you took 2015 year calendar.

Comment: Oh god, you're right I have no idea why I've put 2014 instead of 2015, my bad. And to answer to jac, I want to be able to manage my weeks independently (to show it seperately on an interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from WeekTable w
where
w.WeekStartDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
and w.WeekEndDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

This will give you the full weeks between two given dates.

If you want the partial weeks too just change to:

```
select *
from WeekTable w
where
w.WeekStartDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
OR w.WeekEndDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
OR @StartDate between w.WeekStartDate and w.WeekEndDate
```

Comment: Well, it was that simple actually. Thanks a lot!